# What kind of AWS IAM principal starts with AROA?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have an S3 bucket policy with principal in the below format (21 characters alpha-numeric). The bucket was just created last year but I just can't recognize nor find any reference as to what kind of principal it is. Re-saving the policy result in a "Invalid principal in policy" error.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowS3Access",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "AROAU2DKQKXYQKOSDGTGX"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxx/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [IAM Identifiers - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html):

> `AROA` = IAM Role

To discover the `RoleId` for an existing role, use:

```
aws iam get-role --role-name <ROLE-NAME>
```

To obtain a list of all IAM Roles and their associated `RoleId`, use:

```
aws iam list-roles
```

It is possible that the role being referenced has since been deleted, thus preventing the bucket policy from being successfully saved.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out the IAM policies don't store principals solely as the friendly string we usually see, they store them as unique identifiers.  This is to prevent new users with the same name as retired old users from inheriting the old users' permissions. From the [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html#identifiers-unique-ids):

## Unique identifiers

When IAM creates a user, user group, role, policy, instance profile, or server certificate, it assigns to each resource a unique ID that looks like this:

AIDAJQABLZS4A3QDU576Q

For the most part, you use friendly names and ARNs when you work with IAM resources. That way you don't need to know the unique ID for a specific resource. However, the unique ID can sometimes be useful when it isn't practical to use friendly names.

One example reuses friendly names in your AWS account. Within your account, a friendly name for a user, user group, or policy must be unique. For example, you might create an IAM user named David. Your company uses Amazon S3 and has a bucket with folders for each employee. The bucket has a resource-based policy (a bucket policy) that allows users access only their own folders in the bucket. Suppose that the employee named David leaves your company and you delete the corresponding IAM user. But later another employee named David starts and you create a new IAM user named David. If the bucket policy specifies the David IAM user, the policy allows the new David to access information that was left by the former David.

However, every IAM user has a unique ID, even if you create a new IAM user that reuses a friendly name you deleted before. In the example, the old IAM user David and the new IAM user David have different unique IDs. You can create resource-based policies that grant access by unique ID and not just by user name. Doing so reduces the chance that you could inadvertently grant access to information that an employee should not have.

Another example where user IDs can be useful is if you maintain your own database (or other store) of IAM user information. The unique ID can provide a unique identifier for each IAM user you create. This is the case when you have IAM users that reuse a name, as in the previous example.